# How lengthy articles or text being stored for a News portal application

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a news portal application. But a little confused about how to store the vast text data in the server. We have SQL Server as the database. So is it good to store the lengthy text in the database or is there a better way than that?

Comment: `VARCHAR(MAX)` can store up to **2 GB** of text - that's ***200 times*** the entire text of Leo Tolstoj's *War and Peace* - good enough ?

Comment: @marc_s We are also thinking about using nvarchar since varchar doesnt support Unicode characters. but my question is when 1000s of hits/second does make any problem for fetching this large junk of text data.

Comment: OK, so you have **1 GB** (or **one billion** characters) per row then - enough for ***100 times*** the entire *War and Peace* :-) And yes, of course, if you store thousands of copies of *War and Peace* in your databsae, fetching that much data *will take its time* - but typically, news stories are **nowhere near** as big as such a book - and those should be handled just fine by SQL Server - provided you have **a good and well performing indexing strategy** in place!

Comment: @sforsandeep You're expecting thousands of hits per second and have no idea about what the DB engine can handle? Either your expectations are way off, or you're a bit out of your league :)

Comment: @Luaan Yes I've not an idea in what extend can DB engine can play with these large amount of text data..

Answer (score 1):

The [varchar(max)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176089.aspx) and [nvarchar(max)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) are specifically designed for lengthy character data, non-unicode and unicode respectively.

Comment: OK.. Length of data is fine... but my worry is when huge amount of hits takes place /second will cause any lag in text fetching from SQL? I mean a  kinda bottleneck?

Comment: SQL Server is more than capable of supporting 1000's of requests a second if the underlying infrastructure is sized accordingly. See the comment from @Luaan above...